# Seeking Policy Restrictions Data in London and South East?

Tags: data-request, geospatial, uk

I am researching various GIS data sources for London (UK). I was wondering whether anybody can give me pointers of where to get aggregated planning and policy restrictions data i.e. data that shows what you are allowed (or not allowed) to do in certain areas. E.g Flood plain, green space etc.

I can see that that there are separate data sources for Greenbelt (English Local Authority), AONB (ESRI Open Data), Common Land (DEFAR), Flood Plain (EA), also each Local Authority (LA) will have it's own data. However, what I ideally need is an aggregated resource.

Comment: It would be helpful to anyone looking for similar data if you would [edit] your question to include links to the data sources that you've found so far.